# "Catastrophic failure" using XmlSchemaSet.Add after impersonation using .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to update an existing system that targets .NET Framework 3.5 to .NET Framework 4.5. I have cut the problem down to the following reproducible example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string username = "user";
        const string domain = "domain";
        const string password = "pass";

        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        var logonToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        var logonResult = NativeMethods.LogonUser(username, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out logonToken);
        if (logonResult != 0)
        {
            using (var windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(logonToken))
            {
                using (var context = windowsIdentity.Impersonate())
                {
                    const string filename = @"schema.xsd";

                    using (var file = new StreamReader(filename))
                    {
                        while (file.ReadLine() != null)
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    var xss = new XmlSchemaSet();
                    xss.Add(null, filename);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The StreamReader isn't in the original program, but I wanted to check/prove that the file was accessible after the impersonation. Schema.xsd can be any schema. If the schema can't be accessed, I correctly get a permissions denied error. I created an empty schema to ensure the contents of the schema wasn't an issue, and it still has the problem.

This program works unmodified if the project target framework is changed to .NET 3.5. When targeting .NET 4.5, the exception is thrown, but if I remove the windowsIdentity.Impersonate() call, it works without problem (but obviously with the wrong credentials). The issue is in the combination of using impersonation, .NET Framework 4.0 or above, and XmlSchemaSet.Add().

Any ideas?

Comment: `“Catastrophic failure”` - Most hilarious and epic error message ever. I Remember that from the VB6 / .Net Interop days.

Comment: "Method '~' of object '~' " trumps that ;)

Comment: Is it a stand alone schema or does it have other schema dependencies that are being resolved and fail?

Comment: It's a stand alone schema. As I mentioned in the question, I created a new empty schema to test with, which still has the problem. The stack trace (which I didn't include because the question was already long) goes through the System.Configuration namespace, and the exception is thrown within a method/class in the System.Security.Policy namespace. I hope to have time to investigate this further today.